# Read input when debugging console in wsl2 in VS2022

Tags: visual-studio, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

I have created a console application in Visual Studio 2022 that is just the two lines WriteLine and ReadLine. When Debugging it for Windows, a console opens that shows the output and waits for the input. However, if I switch it to debugging for WSL, I get the output in the “Output” window, but I do not find any way of entering any data to stdin of the program, thus getting stuck at the readline. Is there a way of doing this? Maybe have Visual Studio open a console window instead of using the output window in Visual Studio as it does for the Windows application?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately WSL doesn't provide yet a console to read keystroke on VS2022. The better approach I could find was using the default WSL `launchSettings.json` for debugging before the output to found some bug and create a new setting for debugging after the output. The problem is the need of manual attach running console app to the VS2022 debugger. But at least is a workaround.

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "ConsoleApp": {
      "commandName": "Project"
    },
    "WSL2": {
      "commandName": "Executable",
      "executablePath": "wsl",
      "commandLineArgs": "dotnet ConsoleApp.dll [commandLineArgs]"
    },
    "WSL": {
      "commandName": "WSL2",
      "distributionName": ""
    }
  }
}
```