# Debugging interactive Linux .NET console app from Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wsl-2

I'm trying to debug an interactive console app for Linux on WSL from Visual Studio (not VS Code).

The instructions from Microsoft mostly work:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debug-dotnet-core-in-wsl-2?view=vs-2022

I can run the application, set a breakpoint and hit it. My problem is that the application is interactive and requires input from the console, but no console window is showing, so the WSL process just hangs.

Is there a way to access the console while debugging a WSL app? I do not see any way to edit the debug profile for "WSL".

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70686909/read-input-when-debugging-console-in-wsl2-in-vs2022.