# How to show a console window when debugging a C# app through WSL in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, linux, windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've followed the instructions shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debug-dotnet-core-in-wsl-2?view=vs-2022) to get WSL running, and I can successfully debug my C# application on Windows in a Linux environment.

The problem is that by default, there is no console shown for a Console App if I run through WSL. The VS Immediate window is functional, so I can see the output of my application, but I can't use `Console.ReadLine()` for example.

Any help with a visual studio setting, or a programmatic way to allocate a console in WSL during runtime is appreciated.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70686909/read-input-when-debugging-console-in-wsl2-in-vs2022